# Why such a simple idea as the euclidean vector started developing so late, i.e. around the time of complex numbers?

Tags: math-history

This question is based on the introduction to the book "A History of Vector Analysis" by Michael J. Crowe which can be found here: https://web.archive.org/web/20040126161844/http://www.nku.edu/~curtin/crowe_oresme.pdf

Comment: Strange, I thought that complex numbers go back to 1500s.

Comment: They do. Even according to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#History) the idea for the vector came long after that. It looks so simple and yet it took so much time.

Comment: Well, if the idea of vectors indeed goes to 1500s, then this is not late by any means, Europe was just getting out of the medieval times and science - from the medieval scholasticism.

Comment: Please place the question in the body of the text, and a title in the title. It gets much more clear to read.

Answer (score 0):

@Moishe Cohen gave an answer in the comment section.

> Well, if the idea of vectors indeed goes to 1500s, then this is not late by any means, Europe was just getting out of the medieval times and science - from the medieval scholasticism.